# Is it possible to move safely all the script tags of Facebook and Google in an external script page?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, script-tag, facebook-pixel

I've complited a simple static website whith HTML and SASS but the head section is now cluttered with a bunch of scripts from Facebook, Google and other third parties.

I've learned about differentiation of concerns so I was wondering if it is better to move everything in the scripts tags in an external script sheet and if this operation would be safe to execute.

Here is the head section code:

```
<head>
    <title>Vendi casa con Casa Lugano Immobiliare SA!!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700,700i|Raleway:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.0/cookieconsent.min.css" />
    <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <script>
        !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
            if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
                n.callMethod ?
                n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
            };
            if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n; n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0';
            n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
            t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
        }(window, document, 'script',
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
        fbq('init', '1769570639983938');
        fbq('track', 'PageView');
    </script>
    <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1769570639983938&ev=PageView&noscript=1" /></noscript>
    <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.0/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            window.cookieconsent.initialise({
                "palette": {
                    "popup": {
                        "background": "#343a40"
                    },
                    "button": {
                        "background": "transparent",
                        "border": "white",
                        "text": "white"
                    }
                },
                "content": {
                    "message": "Questo sito utilizza i cookies per assicurarsi che tu abbia la migliore esperienza sul nostro sito.",
                    "dismiss": "Ho capito.",
                    "link": "Approfondisci",
                    "href": "https://casalugano.ch/informativa-privacy"
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-115738638-4"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-115738638-4');
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0);
            var script = document.createElement("script");

            var src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:'
                ? 'https://www.formilla.com/scripts/feedback.js'
                : 'http://www.formilla.com/scripts/feedback.js');

            script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script.setAttribute("src", src); script.setAttribute("async", true);

            var complete = false;

            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (!complete && (!this.readyState
                    || this.readyState == 'loaded'
                    || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                    complete = true;
                    Formilla.guid = 'csd15aa1-95de-4812-a56c-6e7428ea9dcb';
                    Formilla.loadWidgets();
                }
            };

            head.appendChild(script);
        })();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance!